# Default Xamarin UWP wont deploy to windows phone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a fresh installation of Windows (yesterday), fresh install of visual studio with full Xamarin install package (VS2017) and an up to date windows 10 mobile device.

I made the default Xamarin app and tried to deploy having updated the NuGet packages and I get this Error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error      DEP0001: Unexpected Error: SmartDeviceException - Class not registered [0x80131500] App1.UWP

Considering I have not actually set anything up and this is out of the box, I cannot think of why it would not allow this. Both PC and device are in developer mode.

Comment: What template did you use? Was it the Blank Xamarin.Forms template?

Comment: @BrandonMinnick Yes it is. 
From VS boot up, New Project -> Cross-Platform -> Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms) -> Blank App with all platforms selected and a code sharing strategy of .NET Standard

Comment: apparently it's a known issue for all clean VS installation https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/169784/dep0001-unexpected-error-smartdeviceexception-clas-1.html